# How to load load win32 dll and excute simple win API with firebreath

Tags: c++, winapi, firebreath

I trying to figure out how to execute simple win32 API from NPAPI plugin 
done with firebreath Framework ,
i found this example :
https://github.com/hasegawayosuke/npwin32/tree/master/npwin32

but im not sure if i can implement it in firebreath , can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing magical about firebreath as far as executing a windows API goes.  You'd do it the same way you'd do it from any other C++ application or library.  If you have a specific windows API you want to call then we might be more helpful, but generally I just include the correct header and make the API call -- no need to specifically loadlibrary the .dll myself.

If you really want an example of doing it manually, you can find one in the firebreath codebase itself, in the file [src/PluginCore/Win/SystemHelpersWin.cpp](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginCore/Win/SystemHelpersWin.cpp)